# MySQL, Highcharts: "operand should contain 1 column(s):" error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to render data on to a spline chart by collecting an array of id's:

Controller

```
def student_feedback
        difficulty_ids = current_user.school_user.homework_students.pluck(:difficulty)
        @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where("homework_id = (?)", difficulty_ids).first
    end
```

In my chart:

```
...
       }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Difficulty',
            data: [<%= @homeworks.to_json %>]
        }]
    });
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` WHERE (homework_id = (4,2,1,2,3)) ORDER BY `homework_students`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

The data being collected is correct. Is this just a syntax error? I have toyed around a little bit. Removing the brackets from "homework_id = ?" gives same result...can provide more code if needed.

Thanks

Thanks @the12

Tried this

```
def student_feedback
        difficulty_ids = current_user.school_user.homework_students.pluck(:difficulty)
        @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where(["homework_id = ?", difficulty_ids]).first
    end
```

But this returns error `

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` WHERE (homework_id = 4,2,1,2,3) ORDER BY `homework_students`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1`
```

Where it says homework_id = 4,2,1... these numbers are actually from a column called "difficulty" - maybe something is off in the statement above in the controller?

Comment: The portion after `.where` should have square brackets , and the  parentheses around the question mark is not necessary. `HomeworkStudent.where(["homework_id = ?", difficulty_ids]).first`

Comment: @the12 Thanks! You mean like this? @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where(["homework_id = ?"], difficulty_ids).first ? With this I get error "undefined method `%' for ["homework_id = ?"]:Array"

Comment: No, just copy and paste the solution above. The syntax works like this: `where(["column_name=?", column_value])`. The way you're writing it with the question mark, you have to put in an array. If you just wanted a string version, you could write instead, `.where("homework_id = difficulty_ids").first`.

Comment: Strange, I still get same error as before Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` WHERE (homework_id = 4,2,1,2,3) ORDER BY `homework_students`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1     I'll update op...

Comment: Is homework_id a column in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the SQL error.. `difficulty_ids` is an array, as evidenced by the SQL statement it produces:

```
 WHERE (homework_id = 4,2,1,2,3)
```

Since `homework_id = difficulty_ids`, it is an array. You have to make sure that the `homework_id` is equivalent to a single number only in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem I just don't know the syntax. The numbers are right and the ones i'm trying to plot in the graph...

Comment: If the answer, answered the question, which was what does the bug mean, then you should select it as the accepted one.  If you want help as to how to write the proper query, I think it should be a separate question, as you'll  probably need to provide more information as what rows you want, info about your database, and how difficulty_ids is calculated. It would just be easier to read on a new question.

Comment: Yep, it answers the question of what the problem is...which is good. But i'm still stuck :( I can ask another question and give more details on the db table if that would help?

Comment: Yeah ask another question. You should provide details on your database (column definitions), what query you specifically want to target (i.e: I want all rows that have these values), and mention the value of difficulty_ids which is (4,3,1,2,3). I'd also put up code you've already tried, that way people would be more inclined to help.

Comment: @12 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317114/mysql-highcharts-operand-should-contain-1-columns-error-follow-up over here!