# MySQL, Highcharts: “operand should contain 1 column(s):” error (follow up)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to render data on to a spline chart by collecting an array of id's:

Controller

```
def student_feedback
        difficulty_ids = current_user.school_user.homework_students.pluck(:difficulty)
        @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where("homework_id = (?)", difficulty_ids).first
    end
```

The table I am targeting is called homework_students:

```
create_table "homework_students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "school_user_id", limit: 4, null: false
    t.integer  "homework_id",    limit: 4, null: false
    t.datetime "completed_on"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.boolean  "completed",      limit: 1
    t.integer  "difficulty",     limit: 4
    t.integer  "interest",       limit: 4
  end
```

Each student has many different homeworks and they can assign a difficulty value in the difficulty column for each. I am looking to graph this data for each student.

So in the above controller action I am plucking difficulty figures (1 - 5) for each piece of homework the current user is associated with in an array.

In my chart:

```
...
       }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Difficulty',
            data: [<%= @homeworks.to_json %>]
        }]
    });
```

I tried changing action to this:

```
  def student_feedback
            difficulty_ids = current_user.school_user.homework_students.pluck(:difficulty)
            @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where(["homework_id = ?", difficulty_ids]).first
        end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` WHERE (homework_id = (4,2,1,2,3)) ORDER BY `homework_students`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

The data being collected is correct. Though it says "homework_id = 4,2.." (this is not correct, those are the difficulty values). I suspect this is just a syntax error. I have toyed around a little bit. Can provide more code if needed.

I understand the problem but it's just the syntax...

Much appreciate any help. Thanks

UPDATE: Some progress...

```
      },
series: [{
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
    name: 'Difficulty',
    data: <%= Homework.get_difficulty.to_json %>
     },
```

In my homework.rb model:

```
def self.get_difficulty
      HomeworkStudent.pluck(:difficulty)
    end
```

This produces:

[image]

But this is obviously for all records whereas I only want current user's to show and I don't know how to get the dates set up properly (updated_at attribute).

Comment: For the query you want to find, do you want to find all rows that contain a value of difficulty_ids (i.e: all rows with id 4,2,1,2 OR 3)? And do you want duplicate rows of the same value --> there are two values of the number 2?

Comment: @the12 Hi, thanks, yes, so put simply what I want to do is graph on a spline chart the difficulty values against the updated_at attributes of each record. Difficulty on the y axis and the updated_at date on the x axis. Duplicates are fine as the user chooses 1 - 5 in the view so some will be the same. It's a basic line chart really.

Comment: @the12 I was going to try your proposed solution but it disappeared! Just to clarify it has to be dynamic, a user can have more than 5 pieces of homework and thus more than 5 difficulty values. Is using an OR statement like the one proposed ok for this?

Comment: I realized that Tomas Rodriguez's solution would have had the same result as mine. His answer solves the problem of getting your desired query (the one that I previously mentioned in the comments). With `["homework_id in (?)", difficulty_ids]`, you are getting the rows, which correspond to your array in a "or" like manner (rows where homework_id = 4,2,1,2, OR 3). The problem isn't with the query now, it's with your app. I'm afraid without seeing your entire app, it's difficult to know where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @the12 hi, made some progress, I updated op. Good that it's rendering but still it's only suppose to be for current user + not sure on how to get the dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL is wrong, try `"homework_id in (?)"` instead of `homework_id = (?)`, to select rows with multiple values.

Your code should be:

```
def student_feedback
    difficulty_ids = current_user.school_user.homework_students.pluck(:difficulty)
    @homeworks = HomeworkStudent.where(["homework_id in (?)", difficulty_ids]).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but nothing renders and in the page source:  },
        series: [{
            name: 'Difficulty',
            data: [null]
        }]

Comment: Hi @Co2, so the query now works, and you're expecting `homeworks` results, but you're getting 0 results for that query, right ? I see 2 options: a) You may have a data consistency issue, or b) you may need to consider this "empty results" case. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm expecting results from the difficulty column, not homework, maybe I going about it the wrong way in my syntax? From byebug: SchoolUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `school_users`.* FROM `school_users` WHERE `school_users`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  SELECT `homework_students`.`difficulty` FROM `homework_students` WHERE `homework_students`.`school_user_id` = 10001
Return value is: nil